# Что означает \p{Punct} в регулярном выражении?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Посдкажите что делает данное регулярное выражение с \p{Punct}

```
  line = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
```

Answer (score 6):

Через `\p{}` обозначаются символьные классы.

Список классов для Java можно посмотреть в документации к [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

В частности по `\p{Punct}` в документации написано:

> `\p{Punct}`   Punctuation: One of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~ ``
>
> `\p{Punct}`   Знаки пунктуации: Один из `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``

Соответственно, данный код удаляет из `line` знаки пунктуации

Comment: благодарю за помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если считаете мой ответ исчерпывающим, то можете [отметить его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Для этого нажмите на серую галку слева от ответа.